# Submit PDF Form Data to Database

Tags: php, database, pdf, cgi

What is the most efficient and simplest way to submit a filled in PDF form that resides on a users local machine (not on the server) to a database? is this possible? I have looked online and have seen CGI being mentioned a lot but I prefer to use something like PHP.

If the document resided on the server then using something like PHP would not be so difficult to handle this, but what if the PDF document is sitting on a local machine? What approach can we take to send the data over to a database then?

Comment: You want to send local data to server DB..?done

Comment: Data that is filled in from the PDF form yes.

Comment: WhyWhy dont you just place the PDF on the server too just as the other files that will handle the pdf submisions..?done

Comment: The PDF files will be on users local machines, not on a server. This is due to allow PDF form data to be saved on the file system to prevent connectivity issues if the PDF form was to be online.

Comment: So, the database is on a server? Is the server primarily a file server or a web server?